# JHipster and auth0, Error: auth is not defined?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, undefined, jhipster, auth0

I've run the tutorial below, integrating JHipster with auth0. 
https://auth0.com/blog/quicktip-use-jhipster/

When I click on the account signin option I get below, any help would be appreciated!

Many Thanks, KieranH

Error: auth is undefined
open@http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/components/login/login.service.js:23:17
+ more(needed at least 10 reputations to post more the 2 links).

Comment: This tutorial is for JHipster 3.0.0 which is rather old, so you have to adapt it to current version. Open the browser console and check whether all js files were loaded, you may have an error there, gulp build may have not run yet and so your index.html may not have been updated to include auth0 js files.

Comment: Hi Gael, We ran the gulp file so the index.html and js scripts are all updated, but bower.json specifies angular to use the latest ver of auth0-lock which right now is ver 10+ and is not supported by angular 1.x. We have tried changing the version to previous version 9.2.1 to no avail. Any other thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Cheers, KieranH

Comment: Have you tried to use `overrides` property in your project's `bower.json`to specify the versions you want? https://roots.io/using-bootstrap-with-bower-how-to-override-bower-packages/